# SPARQL finding all tuples with same maximum values

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, ontology

I've property named mobileWarrantyYear.

Now I want to fetch all the mobiles with highest available warranty years.

For instance if I have mobile m1 having warranty 1Y, mobile m2 and mobile m3 having warranty 3Y then I want to return mobile m2 and m3.

This is what I've tried so far but it gives me syntac error in filter clause.

How can I implement this logic?

```
PREFIX ns: <http://www.semanticweb.org/cs/ontologies/2019/2/untitled-ontology-2#>
Select * where 
{
?s ns:mobileWarrantyYear ?o
FILTER(?o =  (SELECT * WHERE { ?s ns:mobileWarrantyYear  ?o } ORDER BY DESC(?o) LIMIT 1)
}
```

Basically, I've tried to match the highest warranty year mobile against all the mobile warranty years to see if there are also more mobile available that has the same highest warranty period.

Sorry for the blunt try but this is what I have come up with after hours of struggling.

Any better idea will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: the idea is to use a subquery in which you compute the max value, i.e. `Select * where 
{
?s ns:mobileWarrantyYear ?o filter(?o = ?maxVal) {select (max(?o) as ?maxVal) where {?s ns:mobileWarrantyYear ?o}}}`

Comment: @AKSW working perfectly and also you opened a new dimension for me, Thanks a lot!